# what is `typename...` syntax in C++ template?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, typename

Just found this piece of code in a Program(C++) file:

```
template <typename blah, typename... Args>
const <some-type> bof(<some-parameters>, Args&&... args) const
{
    return breck(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

I am wondering:

1. what is the three dots after the `typename`?
2. Intuitively looks like in this way we can pass multiple arguments? Looking for some official term/reference for it?

Comment: It's the syntax for a *variadic template*. You can see that someone has already added that tag. It's a C++11 onwards thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is called parameter pack, you can read more here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack

Indeed, you can use `Args...` for unpacking multiple arguments in function or class templates, when you don't know ahead of time how many templated parameters there is going to be.